# A voucher with 5% Discount on Second Purchase - Magento

Tags: magento, discount

I have to create a voucher in the magento. I need to offer 5% off on Second Purchase of Each User How I can go for a voucher using this rule?

Comment: It is not Spam.....I need to know hwo it would write ? I saw many tutorials on How to add 5% off on first purchase. Buit I never see any tips on adding 5% off on second purchase.

Comment: I tried everything.....I don't want to go for any extension. But I couldn't get my Order History in the place where we are adding rules for shopping cart. Please guide me to create a voucher with 5% on second purchase. Which Attribute we should use for this?

Comment: Have a look at this extension,
https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/repeated-sales